# Can't execute javascript from com.ibm.rcp.browser.service.WebBrowser on Mac. It works on Windows and Linux

Tags: javascript, macos, mozilla

1. I used WebBrowser.XULRUNNER_SERVICE to construct an instance of com.ibm.rcp.browser.service.WebBrowser.
2. I have a piece of javascript code that I need to call the  webBrowser's execute() method 
   webBrowser.execute(test);
3. It works fine on both Windows and Linux, and the webBrowser.execute(test); returns true.
4. It does not work on Mac at all.  webBrowser.execute(test); returns false.
5. I put in a simple alert message right at the first of the javascript code.
               String e0 = new String("alert(\'step 0 \');" + "\n");
   I can see this alert box on Windows and Linux, but I don't see that on Mac.

Is this a known Mozilla  bug?

Thanks.